# I'm trying to fill a circle with an image but no method I use is working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to put an image into the circles however I tried the fill/pattern things and nothing worked? I might have been doing it wrong but I tried like everything I could think of. Does anyone have any ideas on how to make this work with an image?

I wish they made a context.fillstyle= image/url  option tbh.

It would be really helpful if you could show how to do it and where to put said code in the code I have written too, thank you.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 var canvas = $("#gameCanvas");
 var context = canvas.get(0).getContext("2d");
 
 // Canvas dimensions
 var canvasWidth = canvas.width();
 var canvasHeight = canvas.height();
 
 // Game settings
 var playGame;
 var platformX;
 var platformY;
 var platformOuterRadius;
 var platformInnerRadius;
 var asteroids; // Array that holds all the asteroids
 var player;
 var playerOriginalX;
 var playerOriginalY;
 var playerSelected;
 var playerMaxAbsVelocity;
 var playerVelocityDampener;
 var powerX;
 var powerY;
 var score;
 
 // Game UI
 var ui = $("#gameUI");
 var uiIntro = $("#gameIntro");
 var uiStats = $("#gameStats");
 var uiComplete = $("#gameComplete");
 var uiPlay = $("#gamePlay");
 var uiReset = $(".gameReset");
 var uiRemaining = $("#gameRemaining");
 var uiScore = $(".gameScore");

  var PenguinBall = $("#PenguinBall").get(0);
  var PenguinPins = $("#PenguinPins").get(0);
  
 // Class that defines new asteroids to draw
 var Asteroid = function(x, y, radius, mass, friction) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.radius = radius;
  this.mass = mass;
  this.friction = friction;
  
  this.vX = 0;
  this.vY = 0;
  
  this.player = false;
 };
 
 // Reset player
 function resetPlayer() {
  player.x = playerOriginalX;
  player.y = playerOriginalY;
  player.vX = 0;
  player.vY = 0;
 };
 
 // Reset and start the game
 function startGame() {
  // Reset game stats
  uiScore.html("0");
  uiStats.show();
  
  // Set up initial game settings
  playGame = false;
  platformX = canvasWidth/2;
  platformY = 150;
  platformOuterRadius = 100;
  platformInnerRadius = 75;
  asteroids = new Array();
  playerOriginalX = canvasWidth/2;
  playerOriginalY = canvasHeight-150;
  playerSelected = false;
  playerMaxAbsVelocity = 30;
  playerVelocityDampener = 0.3;
  powerX = -1;
  powerY = -1;
  score = 0;
  
  // Set up player asteroid
  var pRadius = 15;
  var pMass = 10;
  var pFriction = 0.97;
  player = new Asteroid(playerOriginalX, playerOriginalY, pRadius, pMass, pFriction);
  player.player = true;
  asteroids.push(player);
  
  // Set up other asteroids
  var outerRing = 8; // Asteroids around outer ring
  var ringCount = 3; // Number of rings
  var ringSpacing = (platformInnerRadius/(ringCount-1)); // Distance between each ring
  
  for (var r = 0; r < ringCount; r++) {
   var currentRing = 0; // Asteroids around current ring
   var angle = 0; // Angle between each asteroid
   var ringRadius = 0;
   
   // Is this the innermost ring?
   if (r == ringCount-1) {
    currentRing = 1;
   } else {
    currentRing = outerRing-(r*3);
    angle = 360/currentRing;
    ringRadius = platformInnerRadius-(ringSpacing*r);
   };
   
   for (var a = 0; a < currentRing; a++) {
    var x = 0;
    var y = 0;
    
    // Is this the innermost ring?
    if (r == ringCount-1) {
     x = platformX;
     y = platformY;
    } else {
     x = platformX+(ringRadius*Math.cos((angle*a)*(Math.PI/180)));
     y = platformY+(ringRadius*Math.sin((angle*a)*(Math.PI/180)));
    };
   
    var radius = 10;
    var mass = 5;
    var friction = 0.95;
    
    asteroids.push(new Asteroid(x, y, radius, mass, friction));
   };
  };
  
  uiRemaining.html(asteroids.length-1);
  
  // Code from Chapter 5 (Accessing pixel values)
  $(window).mousedown(function(e) {
   if (!playerSelected && player.x == playerOriginalX && player.y == playerOriginalY) {
    var canvasOffset = canvas.offset();
    var canvasX = Math.floor(e.pageX-canvasOffset.left);
    var canvasY = Math.floor(e.pageY-canvasOffset.top);
    
    if (!playGame) {
     playGame = true;
     animate();
    };
    
    var dX = player.x-canvasX;
    var dY = player.y-canvasY;
    var distance = Math.sqrt((dX*dX)+(dY*dY));
    var padding = 5;
    
    if (distance < player.radius+padding) {
     powerX = player.x;
     powerY = player.y;
     playerSelected = true;
    };
   };
  });
  
  $(window).mousemove(function(e) {
   if (playerSelected) {
    var canvasOffset = canvas.offset();
    var canvasX = Math.floor(e.pageX-canvasOffset.left);
    var canvasY = Math.floor(e.pageY-canvasOffset.top);
   
    var dX = canvasX-player.x;
    var dY = canvasY-player.y;
    var distance = Math.sqrt((dX*dX)+(dY*dY));
    
    if (distance*playerVelocityDampener < playerMaxAbsVelocity) {
     powerX = canvasX;
     powerY = canvasY;
    } else {
     var ratio = playerMaxAbsVelocity/(distance*playerVelocityDampener);
     powerX = player.x+(dX*ratio);
     powerY = player.y+(dY*ratio);
    };
   }; 
  });
  
  $(window).mouseup(function(e) {
   if (playerSelected) {
    var dX = powerX-player.x;
    var dY = powerY-player.y;

    player.vX = -(dX*playerVelocityDampener);
    player.vY = -(dY*playerVelocityDampener);
    
    uiScore.html(++score);
   };
   
   playerSelected = false;
   powerX = -1;
   powerY = -1;
  });
  
  // Start the animation loop
  animate();
 };
 
 // Initialize the game environment
 function init() {
  uiStats.hide();
  uiComplete.hide();
  
  uiPlay.click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   uiIntro.hide();
   startGame();
  });
  
  uiReset.click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   uiComplete.hide();
   startGame();
  });
 };
 
 // Animation loop that does all the fun stuff
 function animate() {  
  // Clear
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
  
  // Draw platform
  context.fillStyle = "rgb(222, 225, 255)";
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(platformX, platformY, platformOuterRadius, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
  context.closePath();
  context.fill();

  // Draw player power line
  if (playerSelected) {
   context.strokeStyle = "rgb(255, 255, 255)";
   context.lineWidth = 3;
   context.beginPath();
   context.moveTo(player.x, player.y);
   context.lineTo(powerX, powerY);
   context.closePath();
   context.stroke();
  };
  
  context.fillStyle = "rgb(31, 32, 34)";
  
  
  
  // Loop through every asteroid
  var deadAsteroids = new Array();
  var asteroidsLength = asteroids.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < asteroidsLength; i++) {
   var tmpAsteroid = asteroids[i];
   
   for (var j = i+1; j < asteroidsLength; j++) {
    var tmpAsteroidB = asteroids[j];
    
    var dX = tmpAsteroidB.x - tmpAsteroid.x;
    var dY = tmpAsteroidB.y - tmpAsteroid.y;
    var distance = Math.sqrt((dX*dX)+(dY*dY));
    
    if (distance < tmpAsteroid.radius + tmpAsteroidB.radius) {        
     var angle = Math.atan2(dY, dX);
     var sine = Math.sin(angle);
     var cosine = Math.cos(angle);
     
     // Rotate asteroid position
     var x = 0;
     var y = 0;
     
     // Rotate asteroidB position
     var xB = dX * cosine + dY * sine;
     var yB = dY * cosine - dX * sine;
      
     // Rotate asteroid velocity
     var vX = tmpAsteroid.vX * cosine + tmpAsteroid.vY * sine;
     var vY = tmpAsteroid.vY * cosine - tmpAsteroid.vX * sine;
     
     // Rotate asteroidB velocity
     var vXb = tmpAsteroidB.vX * cosine + tmpAsteroidB.vY * sine;
     var vYb = tmpAsteroidB.vY * cosine - tmpAsteroidB.vX * sine;
     
     // Conserve momentum
     var vTotal = vX - vXb;
     vX = ((tmpAsteroid.mass - tmpAsteroidB.mass) * vX + 2 * tmpAsteroidB.mass * vXb) / (tmpAsteroid.mass + tmpAsteroidB.mass);
     vXb = vTotal + vX;
     
     // Move asteroids apart
     // CHANGE THIS IN PREVIOUS CHAPTER
     xB = x + (tmpAsteroid.radius + tmpAsteroidB.radius);
     
     // Rotate asteroid positions back
     tmpAsteroid.x = tmpAsteroid.x + (x * cosine - y * sine);
     tmpAsteroid.y = tmpAsteroid.y + (y * cosine + x * sine);
     
     tmpAsteroidB.x = tmpAsteroid.x + (xB * cosine - yB * sine);
     tmpAsteroidB.y = tmpAsteroid.y + (yB * cosine + xB * sine);
     
     // Rotate asteroid velocities back
     tmpAsteroid.vX = vX * cosine - vY * sine;
     tmpAsteroid.vY = vY * cosine + vX * sine;
     
     tmpAsteroidB.vX = vXb * cosine - vYb * sine;
     tmpAsteroidB.vY = vYb * cosine + vXb * sine;
    };
   };
   
   // Calculate new position
   tmpAsteroid.x += tmpAsteroid.vX;
   tmpAsteroid.y += tmpAsteroid.vY;
   
   // Friction
   if (Math.abs(tmpAsteroid.vX) > 0.1) {
    tmpAsteroid.vX *= tmpAsteroid.friction;
   } else {
    tmpAsteroid.vX = 0;
   };
   
   if (Math.abs(tmpAsteroid.vY) > 0.1) {
    tmpAsteroid.vY *= tmpAsteroid.friction;
   } else {
    tmpAsteroid.vY = 0;
   };
   
   // Platform checks
   if (!tmpAsteroid.player) {
    var dXp = tmpAsteroid.x - platformX;
    var dYp = tmpAsteroid.y - platformY;
    var distanceP = Math.sqrt((dXp*dXp)+(dYp*dYp));
    if (distanceP > platformOuterRadius) {
     // Kill asteroid
     if (tmpAsteroid.radius > 0) {
      tmpAsteroid.radius -= 2;
     } else {
      deadAsteroids.push(tmpAsteroid);
     };
    };
   };
   
   // Check to see if you need to reset the player
   // If player was moving, but is now still
   if (player.x != playerOriginalX && player.y != playerOriginalY) {
    if (player.vX == 0 && player.vY == 0) {
     resetPlayer();
    } else if (player.x+player.radius < 0) {
     resetPlayer();
    } else if (player.x-player.radius > canvasWidth) {
     resetPlayer();
    } else if (player.y+player.radius < 0) {
     resetPlayer();
    } else if (player.y-player.radius > canvasHeight) {
     resetPlayer();
    };
   };
   
   context.beginPath();
   context.arc(tmpAsteroid.x, tmpAsteroid.y, tmpAsteroid.radius, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
   context.closePath();
  
   context.fill();
  };
  
  var deadAsteroidsLength = deadAsteroids.length;
  if (deadAsteroidsLength > 0) {
   for (var di = 0; di < deadAsteroidsLength; di++) {
    var tmpDeadAsteroid = deadAsteroids[di];
    asteroids.splice(asteroids.indexOf(tmpDeadAsteroid), 1);
   };
   
   var remaining = asteroids.length-1; // Remove player from asteroid count
   uiRemaining.html(remaining);
   
   if (remaining == 0) {
    // Winner!
    playGame = false;
    uiStats.hide();
    uiComplete.show();

    // Reset event handlers
    $(window).unbind("mousedown");
    $(window).unbind("mouseup");
    $(window).unbind("mousemove");
   };
  };
  
  if (playGame) {
   // Run the animation loop again in 33 milliseconds
   setTimeout(animate, 33);
  };
 };
 
 init();
});
```

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; } 
html, body { height: 100%; width: 100%; } 
canvas { display: block; } 
body { 
        background: #000; 
        color: rgb(42, 29, 87); 
        font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif ;
        font-size: 18px; 
} 
h1 { 
        font-size: 30px; 
} 
p { 
        margin: 0 20px; 
} 
a { 
        color: rgb(213, 217, 255); 
        text-decoration: none; 
} 
a:hover { 
        text-decoration: underline; 
} 
a.button { 
        background: rgb(154, 164, 255);
        color: rgb(64, 63, 105); 
        border-radius: 5px; 
        display: block; 
        font-size: 30px; 
        margin: 40px 0 0 45px; 
        padding: 10px; 
        width: 200px; 
} 
a.button:hover { 
        background: rgb(154, 135, 255); 
        color: rgb(42, 29, 87); 
        text-decoration: none; 
} 
#game { 
        height: 600px; 
        left: 50%; 
        margin: -300px 0 0 -175px; 
        position: relative; 
        top: 50%; 
        width: 350px; 
} 
#gameCanvas { 
        background: rgb(64, 56, 105); 
} 
#gameUI { 
        height: 600px; 
        position: absolute; /* Places UI on top of the canvas */ 
        width: 350px; 
} 
#gameIntro, #gameComplete { 
        background: rgba(213, 217, 255, 0.5); 
        margin-top: 100px; 
        padding: 40px 0; 
        text-align: center; 
} 
#gameStats { 
  color:rgb(213, 236, 247);
        font-size: 14px; 
        margin: 20px 0; 
} 
#gameStats .gameReset { 
        margin: 20px 20px 0 0; 
        position: absolute; 
        right: 0; 
        top: 0; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
        <head> 
                <title>Baby Penguin Rescue</title> 
                <meta charset="utf-8"> 
                <link href="game.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> 
                <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
                <script type="text/javascript" src="jsgame.js"></script>    
        </head> 
        <body> 
                <div id="game"> 
                        <div id="gameUI"> 
                                <div id="gameIntro"> 
                                        <h1>Baby penguin rescue</h1> 
                                        <p>Knock all the baby penguins into the water so they can get away from the seals.</p> 
                                        <p><a id="gamePlay" class="button" href="">Play</a></p> 
                                </div> 
                                <div id="gameStats"> 
                                        <p>Penguins: <span id="gameRemaining"></span></p> 
                                        <p>Clicks: <span class="gameScore"></span></p> 
                                        <p><a class="gameReset" href="">Reset</a></p> 
                                </div> 
                                <div id="gameComplete"> 
                                        <h1>You did it!</h1> 
                                        <p>Congratulations, you saved all the baby penguins in <span class="gameScore"></span> clicks.</p> 
                                        <p><a class="gameReset button" href="">Play again</a></p> 
                                </div> 
                        </div> 
                        <canvas id="gameCanvas" width="350" height="600"> 
                                <!-- Insert fallback content here --> 
  </canvas>
  <image id ="PenguinBall">
   <source src="images/Penguin.png"></source>
  </image>
  <image id ="PenguinPins">
   <source src="images/Baby_penguin.png"></source>
  </image>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: _"Knock all the baby penguins **into the water** so they can get away from the seals."_  but seals can swim!

Answer (score 0):

I got the code working, and I put in a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/cg0ndk59/5/

```
  context.save();
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(tmpAsteroid.x, tmpAsteroid.y, tmpAsteroid.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
  context.closePath();
  context.clip();

  context.drawImage(img, tmpAsteroid.x - img.width / 2, tmpAsteroid.y - img.height / 2, 50, 50);

  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(tmpAsteroid.x, tmpAsteroid.y, tmpAsteroid.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
  context.clip();
  context.closePath();
  context.restore();
```

the `img` var is declared in the top of your code, so it will be load only one time, if you use the .onload callback you will face some performace issues

Comment: That's helpful but when I try to use my image as a base64 and all that it doesn't load it. any suggestions? All I did was change what was in the var baseimage= ' Right here '; so there should be an issue right?

Comment: can you provide a fiddle with your code? you can change the one I have made and save it.